# how to get all the values in the "as" of each of the case statements in the cdb criteria of findAll in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have a query like e.g

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = array(
        'CASE
         when userid is not null then userid
        end
      as A',
        'CASE 
         when userid is not null then \'D\'
        end
      as H');
    $result = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

when i foreach the $result, am getting objects in each of those results
and I can only get the actual table column like e.g

```
$obj->USERID
```

I want to get the alias that i used in the select statement like e.g

```
$obj->A  OR $obj->H
```

but if I do that, am getting an error, because A and H are not properties of the MyModel

is it possible to get the "as" names as table columns from the result of the findAll?, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

In CActiveRecord, properties are automaticallly detected based on a table schema which model base on, as you can see [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L2351).

So, the simplest way to add properties, is to add fake columns on a table which is the model base on.
Another way is to override `attributeName()` method. You can add properties to the model. see [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L576).